# MVC4 - How can I sum a result of a foreach list?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

My project tracks vacation hours used per employee. I would like to display the Sum of hours used above the foreach result. The vacation index retireves the data for the selected employee.

Model 1

```
public class Employee
    {
        public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string FirstMidName { get; set; }

  public virtual ICollection<Vacation> Vacation { get; set; }
  }
```

Model 2

```
public class Vacation
    {
        public int VacationID { get; set; }
        public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime EventDate { get; set; }
        public int Hours { get; set; }

        public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
}
```

Controller for Model 2

```
public class VacationController : Controller
    {
        private Context db = new Context();

        //
        // GET: /Vacation/

        public ActionResult Index([Bind(Prefix = "id")]int employeeId)
        {
            var Employee = db.Employee.Find(employeeId);
            if (Employee != null)
            {
                return View(Employee);
            }
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
```

View

```
<table>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Employee.LastName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EventDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Hours)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Notes)
        </td>
          </tr>
}

</table>
```

Comment: Use  [`IEnumerable<T>.Sum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534734.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can calculate the sum of hours with the following expression:

```
var sum = Model.Vacation.Sum(vacation => vacation.Hours);
```

You could add it at the top of your view:

```
Sum of hours: @Model.Vacation.Sum(vacation => vacation.Hours)
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm still green at programming.

Answer (score 0):

If you can set another field in the controller, you can sum the list before sending it to the view.

(Using LINQ extensions)

```
var totalHours = employee.Vacation.Aggregate((acc, val) => acc + val);
```