# How to calculate sum of one field in table and put it in an input

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a table in razor and I sent the data by ViewBag from controller

```
<table>
   <thead>
       <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Category</th>
          <th>Price</th>
          <th>Count</th>
       </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
       @foreach(var item in ViewBag.Products)
       {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.Name</td>
                <td>@item.Category</td>
                <td>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" value="@item.Price" />
               </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form-controll" value="@item.Count" />
                </td>
            </tr>
       }
   </tbody>
</table>


<input type="text" class="form-control" value="@Model.TotalPrice" />
```

I want to multiple count and price of each row and put it in another input using javascript. and when the user change the value of input, that input that holds the value could change automatically.
if anyone can help me i would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need javascript for that? Create 2 variables outside of the loop and increment them inside it. `@{ totalCount += item.Count }`

Comment: Instead of multiplying that using JS, just add `Sum` property to your `Product` class, and store your sum for each row there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MVC4 - How can I sum a result of a foreach list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21031049/mvc4-how-can-i-sum-a-result-of-a-foreach-list)

Comment: I Edited the question. sorry for the miss understanding

Comment: You might want to check knockout js. Works well with MVC and is much more simpler and intuitive than the jquery selector chaining hell.

Comment: sure i will read about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If you are using `jquery` then it can be achieve as below.**

You can update your `total` on every key press in `price` or `count` input.

Add some class to your `input`. In my example I've took class as `price`, and class `total` for display sum.

Add `keyup` event as below. Also `trigger` it on `$(document).ready` to initially set the total value.

```js
$('.price').on('keyup', function() {
  var val = +$(this).val();
  var valSibling = +$(this).parent().siblings('td').find('.price').val();

  if (isNaN(val) || isNaN(valSibling))
    return;

  $(this).parent().siblings('td').find('.total').val(val * valSibling);

  var finaltotal = 0;
  $('.total').each(function() {
    if(!isNaN($(this).val()))
      finaltotal += Number($(this).val());
  });
  $('.finaltotal').val(finaltotal);
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.price').trigger('keyup');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Category</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Count</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Name1</td>
      <td>Category1</td>
      <td><input type="text" class="price form-control" value="40" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="price form-control" value="4" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="total form-control" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Name2</td>
      <td>Category2</td>
      <td><input type="text" class="price form-control" value="20" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="price form-control" value="2" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="total form-control" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<input type="text" class="finaltotal form-control" />
```

Comment: *I want to multiple count and price of each row and put it in another input using javascript.*

Comment: @Mamun Third input will display `multiple` of `price` and `count`. Just it's class name is given as `total`.

Comment: @Mamun Ohh yes, you're right. If OP use jquery then only my code will work

Comment: thank you for your answer. it was helpful. but how can I sum total classes and put it in another input?

Comment: @farshidtorkaman Updated answer for `sum` for `total` class values.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var inputs = $('#container input');
inputs.keyup(function() {
  var arr = inputs.toArray();
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length / 2; i++)
    sum += arr[i * 2].value * arr[i * 2 + 1].value;
  $('#result').val(sum);
})
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Count</th>
      <th>Price</th>
    <tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id='container'>
    <tr>
      <td><input type='number' value='1' /></td>
      <td><input type='number' value='2' /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type='number' value='10' /></td>
      <td><input type='number' value='20' /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

Total: <input type='number' readonly id='result' readonly value='202' />
```

Comment: This will sum up all `price * count`s, not what OP wanted. _"multiple count and price of **each row**"_

Comment: *I want to multiple count and price of each row and put it in another input using javascript*

Answer (score 0):

> ***I want to multiple count and price of each row and put it in another input using javascript.***

You can add another `td` in each `tr`. Then loop through all the `tbody tr` to calculate the value:

```js
var tr = document.querySelectorAll('tbody tr');
function calculate(){
  tr.forEach(function(el){
    var td = el.querySelectorAll('td');

    // If there is invalid number in input then no change in total.
    if (isNaN(td[2].querySelector('input').value) || isNaN(td[3].querySelector('input').value))
      return;

    td[4].querySelector('input').value = td[2].querySelector('input').value * td[3].querySelector('input').value;
  });
}

calculate();
```

```css
.form-control{
 width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<table>
   <thead>
       <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Category</th>
          <th>Price</th>
          <th>Count</th>
          <th>Total</th>
       </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Name1</td>
            <td>Category1</td>
            <td><input type="text" oninput="calculate()" class="form-control" value="40" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" oninput="calculate()" class="form-control" value="4" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" /></td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Name2</td>
            <td>Category2</td>
            <td><input type="text" oninput="calculate()" class="form-control" value="20" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" oninput="calculate()" class="form-control" value="2" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" /></td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Name3</td>
            <td>Category3</td>
            <td><input type="text" oninput="calculate()" class="form-control" value="30" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" oninput="calculate()" class="form-control" value="3" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" /></td>
        </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```